# How to add pgsql extension to php in Centos 6

Tags: php, postgresql, centos6, php-pgsql

I want to add pgsql extension to php in Centos 6.

I've tried uncommenting these lines in my `php.ini` file  with no luck:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You've uncommented the windows configuration lines, but you're on a unix system. Uncomment (or add) this line:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands:

```
 $ yum install postgresql-devel
 $ pecl download pdo_pgsql
 $ tar xzf PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2.tgz
 $ ./configure --with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/pgsql-9.5
 $ make
 $ sudo make install
```

Now check that a

```
*pgsql.so
```

file exists in the directory:

```
/usr/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
```

and also extension_dir of php.ini file is set on this directory.
If you want to know the exact path of your `php.ini` file, create a simple PHP file, in your Apache htdocs or var/www directory, with the following content:

```
<?php echo 'ini: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
?>
```

And then browse it.
Finally add one line to your php.ini file:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Comment: that's a lot of work... why not just do:

     yum install -y php-pgsql